# How to solve the error module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Panel'?

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I found others asking the same problem but their situations are not similar with mine. To be brief, I encountered this error while importing pandas, yfinance and statsmodels.api, statsmodels.tsa.stattools on using adfuller test and moving average model as followed.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import yfinance as yf
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-cd11bbf2a7c9> in <module>
      1 import datetime
      2 import pandas as pd
----> 3 import statsmodels.api as sm
      4 import yfinance as yf
      5 from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\api.py in <module>
      5 from . import regression
      6 from .regression.linear_model import OLS, GLS, WLS, GLSAR
----> 7 from .regression.recursive_ls import RecursiveLS
      8 from .regression.quantile_regression import QuantReg
      9 from .regression.mixed_linear_model import MixedLM

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\recursive_ls.py in <module>
     14 from statsmodels.regression.linear_model import OLS
     15 from statsmodels.tools.data import _is_using_pandas
---> 16 from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.mlemodel import (
     17     MLEModel, MLEResults, MLEResultsWrapper)
     18 from statsmodels.tools.tools import Bunch

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\statespace\mlemodel.py in <module>
     19 from .kalman_smoother import SmootherResults
     20 from .kalman_filter import (INVERT_UNIVARIATE, SOLVE_LU)
---> 21 import statsmodels.tsa.base.tsa_model as tsbase
     22 import statsmodels.base.wrapper as wrap
     23 from statsmodels.tools.numdiff import (_get_epsilon, approx_hess_cs,

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\base\tsa_model.py in <module>
      1 from statsmodels.compat.python import lrange, long
----> 2 from statsmodels.compat.pandas import is_numeric_dtype, Float64Index
      3 
      4 import datetime
      5 

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\compat\pandas.py in <module>
     47 if version >= '0.20':
     48     from pandas.tseries import frequencies
---> 49     data_klasses = (pandas.Series, pandas.DataFrame, pandas.Panel)
     50 else:
     51     try:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in __getattr__(name)
    242         return _SparseArray
    243 
--> 244     raise AttributeError(f"module 'pandas' has no attribute '{name}'")
    245 
    246 

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Panel'
```

My pandas and statsmodels are in the newest version.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In the line ```data_klasses = (pandas.Series, pandas.DataFrame, pandas.Panel)```, there is not pandas.Panel.  Not sure what you are looking for but I would start with the pandas doc or the statsmodels docs

Answer (score 0):

`Panel` has been deprecated in the 0.20.x release and completely removed from 0.25 (see [release note](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html)).

If you want to use the code as it is, you'll have to install a pandas version < 0.25 (e.g. `pip install pandas==0.24.2`). But since the error is coming from `statsmodels` you are most likely running an outdated version. Try:

```
pip install -U statsmodels
```